# changing character into timestamp

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I have two columns (`date character varying, time character varying`) in table VM. Now I want to merge these two columns and change the type as a timestamp. can anyone help me out to do this?

Or else 
I want to separate data based on the year (2017, 2018). I used substring(date, '2018') command but it replies with 2017 data showing `NULL` instead of 2017 along with 2018 data.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what exactly the contents of that table is, but something like this should work:

Add a new `timestamp` column (and please find a better name than `"timestamp"` or `ts_column` for it)

```
alter table the_table add ts_column timestamp;
```

Then you need to update the data

```
update the_table
    set ts_column = to_timestamp(concat("date", ' ', "time"), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
where "date" is not null;
```

The above assumes that the date stored in the column named `"date"` and the time stored in the column named `"time"` are formatted as ISO date and time values. If they are not, you need to adjust the parameter to the `to_timestamp()` function. For details on the format mask, [please see the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)

Then drop the old columns:

```
alter table the_table drop "date", drop "time";
```

---

To extract the year from a date or timestamp column, use the [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function:

```
where extract(year from ts_column) = 2018
```

Note that the above will not be able to use an index on `ts_column` to speed up the query.

An alternative way of writing is:

```
where ts_column >= date '2018-01-01' 
  and ts_column < date '2019-01-01';
```

which would be able to use an index on `ts_column`